# Can I use Time Machine to dump Photos?

Tags: time-machine, backup, photos, photos.app

Can I use Time Machine to restore my machine to the iPhoto app without destroying the files that Photos has converted? 
I don't find Photos intuitive and I'm up against the clock on a project (Photoshop) and can't spend time learning how to access file I can see but can't access. Maybe at another time - I just want my old system and thousands of image back where they were.

Comment: did you delete iPhoto? I currently have iPhoto and Photos on my computer and both launch fine.

Comment: No I didn't but although my machine is not much more than a year old iPhoto is out of date but the upgrade is not available in Canada. It worked until I installed Photos

Comment: What upgrade are you referring to? Apple generally releases software worldwide unless there is a specific reason not to.

Comment: Can't open iPhoto but 'Get Info' says version 9.6.   Lots of stuff doesn't appear in Canada  or if it does often after the U.S.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Time Machine to restore iPhoto app and also the iPhoto library before the conversion of Photos app.

1. You have to navigate through Time Machine backups and folder via Finder.
2. Now go to Applications and restore the `iPhoto.app`.
3. After that navigate to the folder containing your iPhoto library and restore it where you want without overwrite the converted Photos library.
4. Exit from Time Machine.
5. Open iPhoto and open the iPhoto library.